# access value in struct through pointer to struct

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, struct

I have a struct:

```
struct example {
    char arr[SIZE];
    char arr2[SIZE];
};
```

Then I have a function that has as parameter, pointer to some defined struct example. How do I access the values for its arr and arr2?

```
void someFunction (const void *ptr1) {

    struct example firstStruct = ...

    /* I want to access firstStruct.arr, firstStruct.arr2 somewhere here */

}
```

Comment: Are you saying `ptr1` is a pointer to a structure? Your declaration of `firstStruct` isn't a pointer.

Comment: Do you expect `ptr1` to be an instance of `example`?

Comment: try this `struct example firstStruct = *(struct example*)ptr1;`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, I'm just curious, what is your reasoning behind just providing code to quick fix problems? I'm asking because I feel that in doing so, the asker may/may not learn his/her mistake. It would be better to provide an explanation of what is currently wrong (if any), how to fix that, why you expect your solution to work, your actual solution and proof that it works.

Comment: @user2378481, What's the reason for the `void *` if it's just going to pretend it's an `example *`? Right now, I can think of wanting to take any type with those specific members, which can be done properly with a template and SFINAE, or wanting to use it in something like `qsort`, which can be done by using one like `std::sort` that takes any function-like object, meaning your parameter can simply be the right type. Unless, of course, it's C, in which case the C++ tag is a bit misleading and you're pretty much held back to macros or `void *`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

- Cast the void pointer:

  ```
  void somefunction(const void* ptr1){
      struct example* firstStruct = (struct example*) ptr1;
      char c;

      // some access to array inside struct        
      c = firstStruct->arr[0];

  }
  ```
- Pass pointer to struct as a parameter:

  ```
  void somefunction(struct example* ptr1){
      char c;

      // just use the "->" operator 
      c = ptr1->arr[0];

  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

`struct example *exPtr = (struct example*) ptr1;`

And then, to access a specific member in the struct, just use the dereference operator (->). For instance,

`printf("arr = %s\narr2 = %s", exPtr->arr, exPtr->arr2)`